# Row Index provided is out of range, even after check

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, for-loop

My current code:

```
Remove()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ConGridView.RowCount; i++)
    {
        if (ConGridView.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == Address)
        {
            ConGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

So what I am trying to call the remove function every time a client disconnect. the function will remove the connection address from the datagridview. It works well when clients are disconnection one by one. However, if 100 connections gets dropped and it tries to remove 100 connections in less than a second, than it errors out saying "Row Index provided is out of range". How should I check for that ?

So far I've tried:
Try, catch. 
if (ConGridView.Rows[i] != null), if (i < ConGridView.RowCount)
None of it seem to work so far. I've also got results using (i < ConGridView.RowCount) where i is 26 while RowCount is 24, but the remove at function still activates..

Any idea on this ?

Comment: I've solved the problem using a different way... I've switched to TreeNodeView since that's what I was going to use ultimately. 
Now I can remove as many connection as i want with:
For each(TreeNode TN in ConTreeView)
{
    ConTreeView.Nodes.Remove(TN);
}

Should I mark this as the answer ? Even though it dosen't really solve the problem the way it intended, rather taking a different approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried all the suggestions posted by everyone here, however, the error was still there.

I've solved the problem using a different way... I've switched to TreeNodeView since that's what I was going to use ultimately. Now I can remove as many connection as i want with:

```
For each(TreeNode TN in ConTreeView) 
{ 
   ConTreeView.Nodes.Remove(TN); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this. Your code loops through all the rows in ConGridView, but it deletes them as you do. Therefore, at some point you will try to access an item you have deleted, which will cause the error you described.

Probably the best approach it to iterate through the rows in reverse order. This way, deleting a row at the end won't affect when you access rows at the start.

Comment: do you mean what teppic suggested ?
for (int i = ConGridView.RowCount - 1; i >= 0; i--)
That did not seem to work either.

Comment: is there something like "Try to delete, only if it exist"

Comment: Yes, iterating in reverse *will* work. I've done it many times. If it doesn't work for you, perhaps you should be a little more specific about what "did not seem to work" means.

Comment: Well, how would you test if it exists? If you access it and it doesn't exist that's an error right there. You could test the count property everytime through the loop but I think this is just getting silly. I've handled this many times by iterating the loop in reverse. Problem solved.

Comment: my code right is exactly what teppic suggested. I forgot to mention it's running in a thread if that make any different. When I try to drop 100 connections less than 1 second I still recieve the "Row Index Out of Range Error", where the value of i is the same as the value of total rowcount yet the remove at method is still being activated. It should not activate unless i is lower than rowcount value, am i correct ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you initialise your for loop with the current count of rows and then start removing those same rows from the datagridview. At some point your for loop will try to remove a row at an index that is greater than the number of rows left.

Try this instead:

```
for (int i = ConGridView.RowCount - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (ConGridView.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == Address)
    {
        ConGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
         break;
    }
}
```

Comment: it does not work. 
but with your suggestion, I've realized something and tried this:
for (int i = 0; i < ConGridView.RowCount - 1; i++)

which works a little better but still errors out on big connections drop.

Comment: When using the example I suggested do you still have the same issue or is it a different problem?

Comment: Same issue, however on break, I see something like "cannot evaluate expression because the code of the current method is optimized" when I try to find total current RowCount. Only sometimes though.

Comment: Oh, I just received another error using your method where RowCount was 16 and "i" was also 16, and it attempted the Remove. 
Which is weird because it should not attempt it unless "i" was 15 or lower.

Answer (score 1):

why dont you get the total count to a separate variable and then iterate

```
Remove()
{
    int totalConnections  = ConGridView.RowCount;

    for (int i = 0; i < totalConnections ; i++)
    {
        if (ConGridView.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == Address)
        {
            ConGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is becuase you are modifying the collection your are iterating over. It will be better if you use a temporary array and two loops to remove your entries.

```
Remove()

// You can use an array/list or whatever you want below.
Collection<DataGridViewRow> rowsToDelete = new Collection<DataGridViewRow>();

        for (int i = 0; i < ConGridView.RowCount; i++)
        {
             if (ConGridView.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == Address)
                {
                        rowsToDelete.Add(ConGridView.Rows[i]);
                        break;
                }
        }

       // now remove the marked entries.
       foreach(DataGridViewRow deletedRow in rowsToDelete)
       {
           ConGridView.Rows.Remove(deletedRow);
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you remove an item from an array, it is reconstructed; shifting the remaining elements up by one to remove the gap of the index you have removed.

```
1. guybrush threepwood
2. murray
3. elaine
4. Jimmy Gibbs Jr.
```

If you remove 2. item in here; it becomes this:

```
1. guybrush threepwood
2. elaine
3. Jimmy Gibbs Jr.
```

When you are iterating, imagine:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Count; i++)
{
    if (i == 2) myArray.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

While running this, when i = 3, the element at 3 has changed, you expect it to be 'elaine' but it is 'Jimmy Gibbs Jr.'. One way to fix this is decrease `i` by one if we delete it, making sure that `i` refers to correct value.

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Count; i++)
{
    if (i == 2)
    {
         myArray.RemoveAt(i);
         i--;
    }
}
```

I would go for LINQ in this case, though, everything is easier with that.

```
myArray.RemoveAll(x => x == "murray");
```